# Best database suited to aviation data?

Tags: database-recommendation

I need to store aircraft data such as latitude, longitude, altitude, flight-level, speed, etc.

I will have another database (Postgres), which will contain geo-spacial data that I will need to cross-reference with my aircraft data.

In other words, I will need to pull out of the aircraft database an aircraft and all of its lat, long, altitude & flight-levels over a certain duration. I will then need to use that data retrieved (essentially, a flight path) to query the geo-spacial DB and see if, for example, the aircraft went through clouds...

I will need to extract the whole cloud (and there may be many clouds that the aircraft encounters) from the geo-spacial database, not just a boolean value.

My questions are:

- Is postgres suited to storing such aircraft data?
- If not, which database is?
- If I use MS SQLServer to store my aircraft data and postgres to store the geo-spacial data, will I have trouble... like long query times due to mixing databases? Or, is it absolutely fine?

The geo-spacial data will be massive... 7TB for a year.
The aircraft data will be less, but I cannot put a figure on it.

The results from the cross-referencing will be likely be stored in another database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres is a database system that can very well store your aircraft data. If you already use it for your geo-spcial data and you want to query this with the aircraft data than it is easiest and fastest to store them in the same database. This will also make your life easier since you do not need to know 2 database systems and you need no (difficult) configuration of a link between 2 database systems.

Comment: I cannot store the the data in the same database, but I can use Postgres for both aircraft and geo-spacial data, but I get what you are saying: I will use Postgres for both data. Thank you.